# Prevent document from scrolling while in an element on Mobile

Tags: ios, css, sliders

How do I prevent of the body of the html document from scrolling when I am engaging the "moving-images" slider. Currently a simple thumb swipe sends the pages up or down. This is more noticeable on IOS Devices.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div class = "content">
    <p>....content </p>
    <div class = "moving-images">
    ...a little slider with images.
    </div>
    <p>....content </p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>`
```

Comment: You will probably want to set the body to overflow:hidden and position:fixed

Comment: You could 'lock' your body tag? HTML: `<body class="locked"></body>` and then in your CSS `body.locked { overflow: hidden }`

Comment: Setting position to be fixed, causes the page to jump to the top.